# How to connect localhost Django Rest API to Android emulator?

Tags: android, django, flutter, api, django-rest-framework

I'm new to Django and Flutter. I have working Django Rest Api and I need to connect it to my flutter application. I have trouble connecting it to Pixel 2 API 30 android emulator.
I have corsheaders installed, tried multiple tutorials but it just doesn't work.

My ALLOWED_HOSTS are '127.0.0.1', 'localhost', my IP and also my pc name.
My API used to work perfectly fine, but when I tried to connect my android app, it tried to find port :443, which I don't have. For some reason, right now it gives me an error whenever I run django server.

```
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.

Not Found: /142.250.74.42:443
[21/May/2023 17:59:14] "CONNECT 142.250.74.42:443 HTTP/1.1" 404 1800
Not Found: /216.58.207.234:443
[21/May/2023 17:59:14] "CONNECT 216.58.207.234:443 HTTP/1.1" 404 1803
Not Found: /216.58.207.202:443
[21/May/2023 17:59:14] "CONNECT 216.58.207.202:443 HTTP/1.1" 404 1803
Not Found: /[2a00:1450:400f:803::200a]:443
```

Django API works perfectly fine, I can access my database and admin panel, but I just can't connect my app to it. It searches for 127.0.0.1:443 which doesn't exist. How do I fix this problem?

When I run my app through Google Chrome, it connects but there are other problems. For Chrome I use `BASE_URL = "http://127.0.0.1:8000"` which works fine.

Can you please explain me what is the :443 port?
And how do I properly connect my android emulator to API? I'm so lost

Comment: Your app running on an emulator which runs on the same pc as your server should use ip 10.0.2.2 to connect to that server.

Comment: Further you should not bind your server to any ip.